# Is there a way to get more than 3 mirror images from levels 1-10?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [Mirror Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirror-image) spell (PHB, p. 260)  grants you 3 duplicates. [Combining Magical Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting) (PHB, p. 205) says casting the same spell multiple times does not combine them.

Is there a low level way (under 10th level) through other class features to get more than just 3 mirror images or clone warriors?  I am aware that simulacrum can increase this but I am hoping for something lower level that I somehow missed.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if you can cast *mirror image* and get more than three duplicates? Or are you wanting something else?

Comment: Ideally I would like more mirror image duplicates.. however duplicates of any kind would be acceptable.   I have a player who wants the Naruto shadow clones ability or something close to it.

Comment: Hmm, I think the latter may be too broad, but it may be limited in scope enough. But if your 'gate' is requiring more than 3 to 'beat' *mirror image*, you should state that. Is this needing to be class dependent? Any magical items or limitations (level, classes, items, etc.)

Comment: And are you looking for these duplicates to have mechanically properties in ways similar to *mirror image*, or are you just looking for illusions or physical duplicates?

Comment: Have you considered reflavoring other abilities to replicate the idea of shadow clones? Off hand, I can think of a few examples for a monk. Flurry of Blows could be the creation of a few shadow clones which score attacks before dissipating. Patient Defense could be interposing shadow clones to avoid attacks. And Step of the Wind could be having shadow clones create platforms or throw the monk. (Just be wary of providing utility beyond the normal features by virtue of reflavoring)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There are a couple different spells and abilities that give additional illusory duplicates**

### Cleric of the Trickery Domain

The Trickery Domain offers an additional Channel Divinity option to Invoke Duplicity:

> As an action, you create a perfect illusion of yourself that lasts for 1 minute, or until you lose your concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell).

At a later level, you can get more duplicates:

> At 17th level, you can create up to four duplicates of yourself, instead of one, when you use Invoke Duplicity.

### Wizard of the School of Illusion

Illusionists get the ability Illusory Self at level 10:

> you can create an illusory duplicate of yourself as an instant, almost instinctual reaction to danger. When a creature makes an attack roll against you, you can use your reaction to interpose the illusory duplicate between the attacker and yourself. The attack automatically misses you, then the illusion dissipates.

### Fighter of the Echo Knight Archetype

*Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* introduced a new fighter archetype called the Echo Knight which has the ability Manifest Echo:

> You can use a bonus action to magically manifest an echo of yourself in an unoccupied space you can see within 15 feet of you. This echo is a magical, translucent, gray image of you that lasts until it is destroyed, until you dismiss it as a bonus action, until you manifest another echo, or until you’re incapacitated.

At level 18, you can get more duplicates:

> You can use a bonus action to create two echoes with your Manifest Echo feature, and these echoes can coexist.

### Major Image

While it doesn't serve any additional purpose other than the illusion itself, *major image* can create an illusory copy of yourself:

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible phenomenon that is no larger than a 20-foot cube. The image appears at a spot that you can see within range and lasts for the duration. It seems completely real, including sounds, smells, and temperature appropriate to the thing depicted.

Comment: It seems that Echo Knight and the trickery domain are the way to go.  Thanks!